# bxSlider radio button issue

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using bxSlider to slide a set slides based on some questions. I am using radio buttons to trigger the next action.

The issue is the radio button does not toggle the `div's` from the second slide onwards. It works fine in the first slide.

Have created a jsFiddle to demostrate issue - [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/bE4mw/4/). Select yes for the first question and the response text appears. It does not for the second and so on...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code below...

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul id="sample">
        <li>
            <div class="questions">
                Question 1<br />
                <p>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" class="noAction" />No</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" class="yesAction" />Yes</label>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <div id="noAction" style="display: none;">
                    <p>Thank you.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="yesAction" style="display: none;"><a href="" id="go-next1">Go to Question 2</a></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="questions">
                Question 2<br />
                <p>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" class="noAction1" />No</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" class="yesAction1" />Yes</label>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <div id="noAction1" style="display: none;">
                    <p>Thank you.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="yesAction1" style="display: none;"><a href="" id="go-next2">Go to Question 3</a></div>
            </div>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(function() {
        var slider = $('#sample').bxSlider({
          infiniteLoop: false,
          controls: false
        });

        $('#go-next1').click(function(){
          slider.goToNextSlide();
          return false;
        });

        $('#go-next2').click(function(){
          slider.goToNextSlide();
          return false;
        });

        $(':radio').change(function() {
          var item = '#' + $(this).attr('class');
          $(item).toggle();
        });

    });​
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Very strange ... The problem occurs on the last slide.
I found a work around just move the div class="actions" outside the ul tag and it works.

See modification on [jsFiddle demo forked](http://jsfiddle.net/corinnekm/hPpdU/5/)

Comment: Thank you @Corinnekm. Yes, the behavior is very strange. I am trying to make it work without moving the actions div outside the `ul`. There must be something going on with bxSlider that is causing it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Could you please advice a solution ?